# Stats train probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm having trouble with my stats. The question says that the probability of the Amsterdam train arriving on time is .93, and the probability of the Brussels train arriving on time is .89.

The probability both trains are late is .05.

It asks what the probability that at least one train is on time. I'm not sure what to do. I drew circles representing the probabilities, but I'm not certain what the intersection value is supposed to be. Also, is it correct to say that P(A complement) U P(B complement) = .05?

I think that the complement of P(at least one train arrives on time) is P(no train arrives on time). So I think I need to subtract that probability from 1.

I don't know how to get it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote with $A$ the event that the Amsterdam train arrives on time. Denote with $B$ the event, that the Brussels train arrives on time. You know that $P(A)=0.93$ and $P(B)=0.89$. With $A^c$ denoting the complement of the event $A$, you also know that

$P(A^c \cap B^c)=0.05$,

i.e. the probability of both trains arriving late (not on time) is 0.05.

You want to determine $P(A \cup B)$, i.e. the event that at least one of the trains arrive on time.

You can use that $P(A^c \cap B^c) = P((A \cup B)^c) = 1 - P(A \cup B)$, such that $P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(A^c \cap B^c) = 1 - 0.05 = 0.95$. Note that you only needed the probability of both trains arriving late! The tricks applied above and other rules can be found here: http://stattrek.com/probability/probability-rules.aspx.

For a picture of what is going on:

[image: Picture]

Comment: Thanks. I've calculated the probability of the intersection to be .87. Now it's asking for the probability that exactly one is on time. I'm not sure where to go.

Comment: Yes. $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B) = 0.87$.

For exactly one to be one time, you are interested in the probability that at least one train is on time minus the probability that both trains are on time. In user2825632 this corresponds to Case 1 + Case 2 + Case 3 - Case 1.

A more mathematical argument:
With my notation from above, you are interested in the event $(A \cup B)\backslash(A \cap B)$. Now $(A \cap B) \subset (A \cup B)$ - see the figure - such that $P(A \cup B)\backslash(A \cap B))=P(A \cup B) - P(A \cap B)$, which you should know how to calculate.

Comment: Note that Case 1, 2 and 3 together correspond to $(A \cup B)$, while Case 1 corresponds to $(A \cap B)$.

Comment: P(A U B) - P(A int. B) is only .08. That doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: If they almost always both are one time, the probability that only one should be on time is very small.

Consider the cases: You have now found, that

(i) The probability that both trains are on time is 0.87.
(ii) The probability that both trains are late is 0.05.
(iii) The probability that exactly one train is one time is 0.08.

These 3 events are disjoint (they cannot occur at the same time), and they are also a partition of the space of possible events: One of them must happen. As you can see, the probabilities sum to $1$, so everything is swell.

Comment: A classmate of mine told me he got .5 for an answer, which is why I asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45563/discussion-between-furrer-and-t-1000s-son).

Answer (score 1):

We see that there are four possibilities:

**Case 1:** Both trains are on time.

**Case 2:** Train 1 is on time, train 2 is late.

**Case 3:** Train 2 is on time, train 1 is late.

**Case 4:** Both trains are late.

You should see that the probabilities of each of the cases should add to $1$. (since these are the only possible outcomes). You are given that the probability that both trains are late is $0.05$, so the probability of one of the other three cases is $1-0.05=0.95$. We see that the other three cases can be summarized as "at least one train is on time", therefore the probability that at least one train is on time is $0.95$.